# How to search for a unique sequence in binary data?

Tags: file, search, binary, header, dm-script

I am trying to read a binary file with header. I know certain info is saved after a unique sequence 02 06 08 22 02 02 08 00. How could I find the position of such unique sequence?

I can use

String StreamReadAsText( ScriptObject stream, Number encoding, Number count )

to read the binary file one by one. But I guess it is pretty silly and slow.

Besides, how do i compare the result from StreamReadAsText() when the output is not a actual text (between 00 and 1F in the Ascii Table)?

Then, How do i read the binary file as int8 (the same size as a character in a string).for example, read 02, then 06, then 08 etc...

Any help is welcome and appreciated.

Regards,

Roger

Comment: Related (but not duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/q/34834197/1302888

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already on the right track with reading the file with the streaming commands. However, why would you want to read the stream as text? You can read the stream as any (supported) number, using the tagGroup object as a proxy with `TagGroupReadTagDataFromStream()`.

There is actually an example in the F1 help-section where the streaming commands are listed, which I'm just copying here.

[image: F1 help]

```
 Object stream = NewStreamFromBuffer( NewMemoryBuffer( 256 ) )
 TagGroup tg = NewTagGroup();

 Number stream_byte_order = 1; // 1 == bigendian, 2 == littleendian
 Number v_uint32_0, v_uint32_1, v_sint32_0, v_uint16_0, v_uint16_1

 // Create the tags and initialize with default values
 tg.TagGroupSetTagAsUInt32( "UInt32_0", 0 )
 tg.TagGroupSetTagAsUInt32( "UInt32_1", 0 )
 tg.TagGroupSetTagAsLong( "SInt32_0", 0 )
 tg.TagGroupSetTagAsUInt16( "UInt16_0", 0 )
 tg.TagGroupSetTagAsUInt16( "UInt16_1", 0 )

 // Stream the data into the tags   
 TagGroupReadTagDataFromStream( tg, "UInt32_0", stream, stream_byte_order );
 TagGroupReadTagDataFromStream( tg, "UInt32_1", stream, stream_byte_order );
 TagGroupReadTagDataFromStream( tg, "SInt32_0", stream, stream_byte_order );
 TagGroupReadTagDataFromStream( tg, "UInt16_0", stream, stream_byte_order );
 TagGroupReadTagDataFromStream( tg, "UInt16_1", stream, stream_byte_order );

// Show the taggroup, if you want
// tg.TagGroupOpenBrowserWindow("AuxTags",0)

 // Get the data from the tags
 tg.TagGroupGetTagAsUInt32( "UInt32_0", v_uint32_0 )
 tg.TagGroupGetTagAsUInt32( "UInt32_1", v_uint32_1 )
 tg.TagGroupGetTagAsLong( "Sint32_0", v_sint32_0 )
 tg.TagGroupGetTagAsUInt16( "UInt16_0", v_uint16_0 )
 tg.TagGroupGetTagAsUInt16( "UInt16_1", v_uint16_1 )
```

There is already a post here on site about searching for a pattern within a stream: [Find a pattern image (binary file)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34834197/1302888)
This shows how you would use a stream to look in an image, but you can use the filestream directly of course.

---

As an alternative, you can read a whole array from the stream with `ImageReadImageDataFromStream` after preparing a suitable image beforehand. 
You can then use images to search location. This would be an example:

```
// Example of reading the first X bytes of a file
// as uInt16 data

image ReadHeaderAsUint16( string filepath, number nBytes )
{
    number kEndianness = 0 // Default byte order of the current platform
    if ( !DoesFileExist( filePath ) ) 
        Throw( "File '" + filePath + "' not found." )
    number fileID = OpenFileForReading( filePath )
    object fStream = NewStreamFromFileReference( fileID, 1 )
    if ( nBytes > fStream.StreamGetSize() ) 
        Throw( "File '" + filePath + "' has less than " + nBytes + "bytes." )

    image buff := IntegerImage( "Header", 2, 0, nBytes/2 )  // UINT16 array of suitable size
    ImageReadImageDataFromStream( buff, fStream, kEndianness )
    return buff 
}

number FindSignature( image header, image search )
{
    // 1D images only
    if (        ( header.ImageGetNumDimensions() != 1 ) \
            ||  ( search.ImageGetNumDimensions() != 1 ) )
        Throw( "Only 1D images supported" )

    number sx = search.ImageGetDimensionSize( 0 ) 
    number hx = header.ImageGetDimensionSize( 0 )
    if ( hx < sx )
        return -1

    // Create a mask of possible start locations
    number startV = search.getPixel( 0, 0 )
    image mask = (header == startV) ? 1 : 0

    // Search all the occurances from the first
    number mx, my
    while( max( mask, mx, my ) )
    {
        if ( 0 == sum( header[0,mx,1,mx+sx] - search ) )
            return mx
        else
            mask.SetPixel( mx, 0, 0)
    }
    return -1
}

// Example
// 1) Load file header as image (up to the size you want )
string path = GetApplicationDirectory( "open_save", 0 )
number maxHeaderSize = 200
if ( !OpenDialog( NULL, "Select file to open", path, path ) ) Exit(0)
image headerImg := ReadHeaderAsUint16( path, maxHeaderSize  )
headerImg.ShowImage()

// 2) define search-header as image
image search := [8]: { 02, 06, 08, 22, 02, 02, 08, 00 }
// MatrixPrint( search )

// 3) search for it in the header
number foundAt = FindSignature( headerImg, search )
if ( -1 == foundAt ) 
    Throw( "The file header does not contain the search pattern." )
else
    OKDialog( "Found the search pattern at offset: " + foundAt * 16 + "bytes" )
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am not very familiar with Tags. But I am able to read stream by tags as Int32, Int16 and Double. To my understanding, Int32 has the length like 02 06 08 22, while Int16 has the length like 02 06. It the stream comes like 00 02 06 08, then it will miss this sequence by read Int16. So I will need to read as "Int8" (I don't even know if it is called this way). Then length should only be like 02. In this way I will be sure it won't miss the right header sequence. The problem right now is that I can't read "Int8". Only read stream as text has such length but I can' compare ASCII

Comment: @Roger You could read the data as UInt8 image - IntegerImage(" ",1,0,...) - or Int8 image - IntegerImage("", 1, 1, ...). Or you could search with two passes (one with a 1-byte offset per step). Unfortunately, I don't know of a "GetTagAsUInt8" or "Int8" like command right now.

Comment: Great idea!! I am reading the header as IntegerImage ("", 1, 0, nBytes). The use your FindSignature function to find the sequence (this time it is a image with 8 pixels). I tested with sequence {2,6,8,34,2,2,8,0} it is working great. It found the position of such sequence!! it worked right for sequence {112,0,7,5,1,96,0,34,7} as well. But when I tested it with sequence  {0,7,5,1,96,0,34,7}, it didn't come back with the right position. I am wondering if this sequence to look for has to start with a nonZero value? Besides, Could I search for a substring in the same way from a long string?

Comment: @Roger: You could use such things for strings, but for searching substrings I would rather use the preface 'find' command.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a  modern machine, just load the file into memory, then scan for the sequence using a memory comparison function and a travelling index.

It's not the most memory efficient way of doing things or even the fastest, but it's easy and fast enough, assuming you have resources to burn.

Comment: Unfortuanately there is no such funciton availaible in the DM-script language. However, the idea I posted below is not much differnt in priniciple.